# Problem with Sharepoint Online and Documet Library Internet Explorer

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, internet-explorer

If I open a SharePoint Library in SharePoint Online with Internet Explorer I get a blank site:

[image]

If I open in Firefox it work well and I can see all the documents.

How could I Fix it.

Comment: What version of IE are you using ?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has removed support for older versions Of Internet explorer. So it only works if its IE 10 or above and Edge in case of `Modern list and libraries experience`.

[Differences between classic and new experiences for lists and document libraries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-classic-and-new-experiences-for-lists-and-document-libraries-30e1aab0-a5cc-4363-b7f2-09e2ae07d4dc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

So, if you have the modern experience and need to use IE, you should switch back to the classic list experience using "Return to classic sharepoint" link. If its affecting all users, then just change the tenant level settings to `classic experience` (using above link).

You will find "return of classic sharepoint" in the left navigation as below.

[image]

**To do it on all site collections**

1) Go to the sharepoint admin center url -

```
https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com
```

2) Choose Settings.

3) Scroll down to SharePoint Lists and Libraries experience.

4) Choose classic experience.

[image]

5) Click Ok at below

Now wait for about 24 hours for this to take effect.

Comment: But how to do it on all Site Collection ?

Comment: Check updated answer. Have added screenshot as well. In the settings, click on the Classic experience. You need SharePoint admin permissions to change the settings

Comment: Yes but I should weit 24 Hours ?

Comment: Yes, it usually takes 24 hours for changes to get propagated to all site collections

Answer (score 0):

Please check your IE version is compatible with new SharePoint Document Library view or not?

It is support in Internet Explorer 10 and 11.

Comment: Yes it is. How Could I change to Old Sharepoint Online Documet Library ?

Comment: Go to **Library Settings** --> **Advanced Settings** --> **List experience** and choose Classic experience.It will give you old experience.